# Android: How to check for three conditions (boolean variables) before continuing with the app?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-location

I have an app that requires the detection of location services (FINE_LOCATION) which requires either data or wifi to be enabled as well as the Location or (GPS) to be enabled as well.

I have managed to work around this if one condition is disabled but what I need is if all three services are disabled the app should walkthrough the user to enable them all one after another.
Is there a way of creating a loop or some kind of variable listener to see if all conditions are met?

```
public class dblogin extends AppCompatActivity implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {

MaterialEditText email, password;
Button login, register, anon;
CheckBox loginState,tacState;
TextView tacAgree;
int responseData = 0;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 1;
boolean GPS_ACCESS = false;
boolean WLAN_ACCESS = false;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dblogin);

    if(GPS_ACCESS&&WLAN_ACCESS)
    {
        requestLocationPermission(); //Requires Permission to Location
    }
    else
    {
        requestWLANAccess(); //WIFI IS OFF
        requestGPSAccess();  //LOCATION is OFF
    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    // Forward results to EasyPermissions
    EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
}

@Override
public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
    register= findViewById(R.id.register);
    login= findViewById(R.id.login);
    anon= findViewById(R.id.anon);
    login.setEnabled(true);
    register.setEnabled(true);
    anon.setEnabled(true);

    login.setText("Login");
    register.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#008577"));
    anon.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#008577"));
    // Some permissions have been granted
    // ...
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Permission is already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
    // Some permissions have been denied
    // ...
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please allow access to location to continue using the app.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ViewGroup vg =findViewById(R.id.myView);
    vg.invalidate();
    register= findViewById(R.id.register);
    login= findViewById(R.id.login);
    anon= findViewById(R.id.anon);
    register.setEnabled(false);
    anon.setEnabled(false);
    login.setText(R.string.grantpermission);
    register.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    anon.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            requestLocationPermission();

        }
    });
    }

public void requestLocationPermission() {
    String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
    if(EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, perms)) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        onAccessGranted();
    }
    else {
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "PLEASE GRANT ACCESS TO LOCATION SERVICES", REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION, perms);
    }
}

public void requestGPSAccess(){
    //GPS is not ON
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    boolean network_enabled = false;
    disbaleButtons();

    try {
        gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch(Exception ex) {}

    try {
        network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch(Exception ex) {}

    if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
        // notify user
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(R.string.gps_network_not_enabled)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.open_location_settings, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.Cancel,null)
                .show();
    }
    else
    {
        //GPS is ON
        GPS_ACCESS=true;
        //requestWLANAccess();
    }
}

public void requestWLANAccess(){
    //WIFI is not ON
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
        // wifi is enabled
        WLAN_ACCESS=true;
    }
    else
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(R.string.wifi_network_not_enabled)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.open_WIFI_settings, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.Cancel,null)
                .show();

    }


}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_dblogin);
    requestLocationPermission();
}

private void disbaleButtons()
{
    register= findViewById(R.id.register);
    login= findViewById(R.id.login);
    anon= findViewById(R.id.anon);
    login.setEnabled(false);
    register.setEnabled(false);
    anon.setEnabled(false);
}

private void enableButtons()
{
    register= findViewById(R.id.register);
    login= findViewById(R.id.login);
    anon= findViewById(R.id.anon);
    login.setEnabled(true);
    register.setEnabled(true);
    anon.setEnabled(true);
}

private void onAccessGranted()
{
    final String idDevice = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    email =findViewById(R.id.email);
    password= findViewById(R.id.password);
    register= findViewById(R.id.register);
    login= findViewById(R.id.login);
    loginState= findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    anon= findViewById(R.id.anon);
    tacState= findViewById(R.id.agree);
    tacAgree =findViewById(R.id.terms);


    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(dblogin.this, register.class));
                finish();
        }
    });


    anon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //continue as guest
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.putString("guestmode","anon");
            editor.commit();
            checkScore(idDevice);
        }
    });


    tacAgree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(dblogin.this, agreement.class));
        }
    });



    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (tacState.isChecked()) {
                // Agreed to TAC
                String txtEmail =email.getText().toString();
                String txtPassword =password.getText().toString();

                if ( TextUtils.isEmpty(txtEmail) || TextUtils.isEmpty(txtPassword))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(dblogin.this, "Please fill all the required fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    login(txtEmail,txtPassword);
                }
            }
            else
            {
               //Please agree
                Toast.makeText(dblogin.this, "Please agree to the terms and conditions of usage and privacy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    String loginStatus = sharedPreferences.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.prefLoginState),"");
    String getEmail = sharedPreferences.getString("prefEmail","");
    if(loginStatus.equals("loggedin"))
    {
        checkScore(getEmail);
    }
    else
        {
           //TODO what happens when logged out is the state in the shared preferences
        }
}

// END OF ON CREATE METHOD


private void checkScore(final String mEmail)
{
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog2 = new ProgressDialog(dblogin.this);
    progressDialog2.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog2.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressDialog2.setTitle("Checking Login Data");
    progressDialog2.show();

    String URL = "https://innosens.com.my/dboard/check.php";
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST, URL, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if(response.equals("No Score"))
            {
                progressDialog2.dismiss();
                saveScore("-1",mEmail.toString());
                //Toast.makeText(dblogin.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                saveScore(response,mEmail.toString());
                progressDialog2.dismiss();
                //Toast.makeText(dblogin.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressDialog2.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(dblogin.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
            param.put("email", mEmail);
            return param;
        }
    };

    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    MySingleton.getInstance(dblogin.this).addToRequestQueue(request);

}


public void saveScore(String score, String email)
{
    if ((Integer.parseInt(score))>=0) {
        responseData=Integer.parseInt(score);
        Intent intent = new Intent(dblogin.this, finalscore.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("SCORE", responseData);
        intent.putExtra("EMAIL", email);
        dblogin.this.startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
    else
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(dblogin.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        dblogin.this.startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

}


private void login(final String email, final String password)
{
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(dblogin.this);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Loggin In ");
    progressDialog.show();
    String URL = "https://www.innosens.com.my/dboard/login.php";
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if(response.equals("Login Success"))
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                //Toast.makeText(dblogin.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                if (loginState.isChecked())
                {
                    editor.clear();
                    editor.putString("prefEmail",email);
                    editor.putString(getResources().getString(R.string.prefLoginState),"loggedin");
                    editor.commit();
                }
                else
                {
                    editor.clear();
                    editor.putString("prefEmail",email);
                    editor.putString(getResources().getString(R.string.prefLoginState),"loggedout");
                    editor.commit();
                }


                checkScore(email);

            }
            else
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(dblogin.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(dblogin.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }){

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
            param.put("email", email);
            param.put("password", password);

            return param;
        }

    };
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    MySingleton.getInstance(dblogin.this).addToRequestQueue(request);

} // END OF METHOD LOGIN }
```

Comment: Check in onPermissionResult() either all condition meet or not if not then ask again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, my question is how to create the loop of asking again if not all conditions are met?

Comment: After requesting for permission check in onPermissionResult() function if any permission user didn't allow then ask again.

Comment: For location access that would be true as it is considered as permission under the manifest Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION but for Wifi or Location (Enable) they are just basically phone settings under the LocationManager and WifiManager classes